redirection not working from root path "/" (react-router v6)
I am using React-Router-DOM version 6.25.1. I want the user to be redirected to the home page "/home" if they logged in before. I am using Firebase auth. I check if the user is logged in via the onAuthStateChanged observer provided by Firebase. If there is a user logged in the  promise is resolved, if not it gets rejected. I am using a loader function to do this check. If I call the loader function in my root "/" element the page keeps loading and I am not redirected, however if I do that in other pages such as "/LoginPage" I am able to redirect to the home page "/home".
Here is the structure of my routes:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/LoginPage",
    errorElement: <RouteError />,
    loader: async () => {
      const authPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        onAuthStateChanged(eCommerceAuth, (user) => {
          // this works fine
          if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            resolve(user)
          }
          else {
            reject(null)
          }
        })

      })
      const authenticatedUser = await authPromise
      console.log(authenticatedUser)
      if (authenticatedUser) return redirect("/home")
      return {}
    },
    element: (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginPage />
      </Provider>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/RegistrationPage",
    errorElement: <div>oops something went wrong</div>,
    element: (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RegistrationPage />
      </Provider>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    // this doesn't redirect 
    loader: async () => {
      const authPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        onAuthStateChanged(eCommerceAuth, (user) => {
          if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            resolve(user)
          }
          else {
            reject(null)
          }
        })

      })
      const authenticatedUser = await authPromise
      console.log(authenticatedUser)
      if (authenticatedUser) return redirect("/home")
      return {}
    },
    element: (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <App />
        </AuthProvider>
      </Provider>
    ),
    errorElement: <RouteError />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        element: (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <AuthProvider>
              <HomePage />
            </AuthProvider>
          </Provider>
        ),
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
          {
            index: true,
            path: "SelectedCategory",
            element: <SelectedCategory />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

root.render(
  <RouterProvider
    router={router}
    fallbackElement={<div>I hate routers</div>}
  />,
);

I replaced the onAuthStateChanged observer and the promise with an  object const isAuth = { user: true } and made a condition if (isAuth) { redirect("/home") } to see if the problem is related to onAuthStateChanged but that didn't work as I am getting the same behaviour as before.

Issue
You are redirecting to a nested route under the route with the loader, which re-runs the parent route loader and creates a render-loop. You can't redirect to a nested route like this, but you can redirect to a route outside the auth check.
Example:

Routes nested under "/" can redirect elsewhere, e.g. to "/loginpage"
The "/loginpage" route can redirect into the "/" nested routes, e.g. to "/homepage".

There are other various issues in the routing code like duplicate Redux store providers.
Solution
Suggested refactor:

Single root layout route to render:

Single Redux Provider to nested routes
Single AuthProvider to nested routes
Outlet for nested routes to render their element content into


Move all routes under this root layout route

Update the "/" route loader to redirect to any other route that isn't a nested route, e.g. redirect outside to "/LoginPage"

Remove Provider and AuthProvider from all the nested routes

Render a redirect from the "/" index route to "/home" for authenticated users to correctly get redirected to the home page

Remove the index prop from the SelectedCategory page, there can be only one index route per parent route


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Outlet />
        </AuthProvider>
      </Provider>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/LoginPage",
        errorElement: <RouteError />,

        loader: async () => {
          const authPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            onAuthStateChanged(eCommerceAuth, (user) => {
              if (user) {
                resolve(user);
              } else {
                reject(null);
              }
            });
          });
          const authenticatedUser = await authPromise;

          if (authenticatedUser) return redirect("/home");
          return {};
        },
        element: <LoginPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/RegistrationPage",
        errorElement: <div>oops something went wrong</div>,
        element: <RegistrationPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/",
        loader: async () => {
          const authPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            onAuthStateChanged(eCommerceAuth, (user) => {
              if (user) {
                resolve(user);
              } else {
                reject(null);
              }
            });
          });
          const authenticatedUser = await authPromise;

          if (!authenticatedUser) return redirect("/LoginPage");
          return {};
        },

        element: <App />,
        errorElement: <RouteError />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Navigate to="home" replace /> },
          {
            path: "home",
            children: [
              { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
              {
                path: "SelectedCategory",
                element: <SelectedCategory />,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);


@JohnnyCapreano Sure, that might also work. Not the solution I'd push for though since it kind of couples parts of your code and might be a bit more maintenance in the long run.

what i figured out is to add a condition to ensure that redirection happens only if the path is not "/home" in my appLoader.ts @DrewReese

@JohnnyCapreano Something else to be aware of is that onAuthStateChanged subscribes a listener, so you may want to thoroughly test this implementation to see if you ever need to unsubscribe the auth check in the loaders so your UI isn't redirecting unexpectedly.

I have noticed your code looks much better than mine is it something that u gain with experience to write better code  or it has to do with a  person's intelligence  i don't know why i never thought of using a nested layout like you did there instead of all that repetitive code : <AuthProvider/> etc.. @DrewReese

@JohnnyCapreano LOL, thank you... it almost most certainly comes with experience. I half jokingly let my junior developers know that I likely did it wrong 99 times before I found the right way on the 100th attempt. Intelligence helps but only gets you so far, you should still put in the work and effort and gain the experience. Writing clean and readable/maintainable code should be a goal for everyone writing it.

Would you say that you need to work for tech company  to gain such experience or you can get it from building projects I've asked some of my friends who work in the field all of them say that work experience is different from personal projects experience and working for a company is especially different in that matter.  @Drew Reese

@JohnnyCapreano This is all a bit off-topic for SO, and you don't have enough rep yet for chat, but it's probably more of a "working with a team" versus "working solo" dynamic. When you work alone you are only reading, writing, and reviewing your own code, but when you work with a team you will read/review lots of code you didn't write, and many others will do the same with your contributions. I'd say it's probably a bit more difficult or would take longer to grow as a developer if you only worked solo. I have good work experience but a lot of my growth has come from contributing answers here.
